# JBoss Encoding utf 8

Tags: java, gwt, utf-8, jboss

I had problems with my list grids not showing diacritics correctly and I found out that when I inserted from java into the DB the values were already bugged.

A post here helped and I changed my project properties -> Text encoding -> other -> UTF-8 and this fixed my problem. The thing is this only fixes my problem locally.

What I need to do is on my Jboss server also set the encoding somehow. I can only access this panel because I can't access the configuration files directly. Can I do it from here?

[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated and sorry for this dumb question but I tried everything I could think of with no success. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help you https://community.jboss.org/message/643825#643825

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

Comment: For JBoss < 7, add URIEncoding="UTF-8" to connectors in <jboss_install>/server/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml

Answer (score 2):

To be quite sure, you have something with pageEncoding like this?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<f:loadBundle basename="i18n.messages" var="msg"/>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful for someone:

`Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Filter that intercepts each request in your application, so into this filter you can set the character encoding. There is a thread to this at [developer.jboss](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/222755). The Filter can be as follow:

```
 @WebFilter(filterName = "CharacterEncodingF", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
    public class CharacterEncodingF implements Filter {


   public CharacterEncodingF() {
   }   


   /**
    *
    * @param request The servlet request we are processing
    * @param response The servlet response we are creating
    * @param chain The filter chain we are processing
    *
    * @exception IOException if an input/output error occurs
    * @exception ServletException if a servlet error occurs
    */
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
           FilterChain chain)
           throws IOException, ServletException {

         request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
         chain.doFilter(request, response);

   }

   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
   }

   @Override
   public void destroy() {
   }


}
```