# Container doesn't use UTF-8 to decode URLs

Tags: utf-8, jenkins, jboss7.x

Now, I am trying to use Jenkins. So, I deploy Jenkins.war file in JBoss 7.1.1. And the call from browser using 8080 port. When I click "Manage Jenkins" link, the following warning message is shown.

**"Your container doesn't use UTF-8 to decode URLs. 
  If you use non-ASCII characters as a job  name etc, 
  this will cause problems. See Containers and Tomcat i18n for more details."**

I tried to solve it and Find from internet about this problem. I not see any answer to solve.I don't know how to solve it. Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: [This answer][1] from Stack Overflow should help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226018/jboss-encoding-utf-8

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working for that error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem in JBoss 4.2.2. I solved it by editing `$JBOSS_HOME/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml` and adding `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in  the `Connector`.

`<Connector port="9443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />`

Comment: I tried the same in my Tomcat server 7. It didn't work.